# Where can I ask about forwarded SSH port issues?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

https://serverfault.com/questions/634118/third-host-should-access-ssh-client-on-port-which-is-forwarded-to-server?noredirect=1#comment763418_634118

Although I tried to find the right Stack Exchange site, I seemingly chose the wrong one. Where would have been the right place for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both guest and host OSes are Ubuntu, try [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com). If they were both Unix or Linux systems, you could try [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). If at least one was Windows, [Superuser](https://superuser.com/). It seems you have already got your answer.

I don't use SF, but this line from the close reason seems to be pertinent;

> End user and enthusiast questions are off-topic ...

I'd say you fall in the enthusiast category (I'm not an SF user, so my opinion isn't worth much).